# <a style=display:inline-block;height:8px;width:8px;></a> IE6: only correct size with "&nbsp;"?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, height, width

Internet Explorer (6.0): shows different sizes for the following code: why is that?

```
<a style=display:inline-block;height:8px></a>
<a style=display:inline-block;height:8px>&nbsp;</a>
```

Chromium and FF (my preferred browsers) show the correct sizes both times, but at work I am forced to use IE6.0.

Is there something to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: @ SimeVidas: `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?> 
<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display:inline-block won't work on empty elements in IE6 - therefore the height element is ignored since it requires the display tag.

Comment: what about adding display:block; to all anchors?

Comment: I'm confused as to why an <a> tag would be empty in the first place?

Comment: @Chris: to create some css-based charts with clickable chart points.

Comment: @amosrivera: but that won't keep it inline.

Comment: Truthfully I don't think you can get round this in IE6 short of using a parent tag or inserting some form of content in an <a> tag. Could you use display: block and then use float to keep them inline? Hard to say without seeing the whole thing as a whole!